# How to update only the StatusCode of an entity in MS CRM Dynamics 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to update a Quote status code in MS CRM 2013 via the SDK. The issue is that I **only** need to update the status code and not the state code in the quote. The current State of the quote is Active and the current Status value is 10 (which I need to update to 11). I've tried a few things unsuccessfully so far:

- Using the Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.SetStateRequest(), setting only the Status property:

```cs
    var request = new SetStateRequest
    {
        EntityMoniker = new EntityReference("quote", quoteId),
        Status = new OptionSetValue(11)
    };

    var resp = (SetStateResponse) orgService.Execute(request);

    // throws Exception Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault:
    // "Required field 'State' is missing"
```

- Using the `Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.SetStateRequest()`, setting both Status and the State property (setting the new State to the same current value):

```cs
    var request = new SetStateRequest
    {
        EntityMoniker = new EntityReference("quote", quoteId),
        State = new OptionSetValue((int) QuoteState.Active),
        Status = new OptionSetValue(11)
    };

    var resp = (SetStateResponse) orgService.Execute(request);

    // throws Exception Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault:
    // "The quote cannot be activated because it is not in draft state."
```

- Calling the Update method (passing in a quote instance) in the `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext` class. I don't have the exact code I used when I tried this, but the error I was getting was:

  > "The object cannot be updated because it is read-only."

  I made sure the connection was made using admin user credentials, but it didn't make a difference. I also found a few other posts like this one: [read-only entity error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237152/dynamics-crm-error-the-object-cannot-be-updated-because-it-is-read-only) but that didn't help either.

**Question**

Is there a way to programmatically update the Quote status code without altering the state code? If so, how?

Comment: One think i can think of is that you'r seting status 11 did you created that status for the QuoteState.Active ?
http://mostlymscrm.blogspot.co.at/2012/06/entity-statecodes-and-statuscodes.html

Comment: Yes minohimself, status 11 is created/published for QuoteState.Active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like my issue has to do with the current state of the quote - Active. Apparently, Active quotes cannot be updated for the most part - I wasn't able to update its status reason even through the GUI. I found [this post](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Microsoft_Applications/Microsoft_Dynamics/Q_27780389.html) with a similar scenario.

As the post suggests, I was able to programmatically update my quote status by first sending it back to Draft/In Progress, and then updating its state/status to Active/11.

Answer (score 2):

The `Status Reason` (`statuscode` field) of a entity depends on the `Status` (`statecode` field) value.

For example the standard values for a Quote are the following

[image]

so inside your `SetStateRequest` you need to set the a valid combination (for example you can't set a quote to be `Active` and `Revised`) specifying both the values.

In your question you wrote that you are using custom `Status Reason`, you need to check under which `Status` you added them and try again.

Comment: Yes Guido, Active/11 is a valid combination